# How do I mock the ApplicationUserManager for unit testing using nsubstitute and nunit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nunit, nsubstitute

I am having a problem in mocking out the `ApplicationUserManager` class using nsubstitute and nunit for testing my action method. Here is the way am mocking the class.

```cs
var _userManager = Substitute.For<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

In my system under test, am injecting the class using constructor injection. When I run the test, i get this error message.

```cs
Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: JobHub.Web.Identity.ApplicationUserManager.
Could not find a parameterless constructor.
```

My question is how do I properly mock this class using NSubstitue as am using the `SetPhoneNumberAsync()`method of the class.

**EDIT**
By the way, here is the piece of code that am trying to test

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserProfileView model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); 

        var profile = model.MapToProfile(userId);

        if (CommonHelper.IsNumerics(model.PhoneNo))
        {
            await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(userId, model.PhoneNo);
        }

        if (model.ProfileImage != null)
        {
            profile.ProfileImageUrl = await _imageService.SaveImage(model.ProfileImage);
        }

        _profileService.AddProfile(profile);
        _unitofWork.SaveChanges();

        //Redirect to the next page (i.e: setup experiences)
        return RedirectToAction("Skills", "Setup");
    }
    return View("UserProfile", model);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when [substituting for a concrete class](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/), but the required constructor arguments have not been provided. If a `MyClass` constructor takes two arguments, it can be substituted like this:

```
var sub = Substitute.For<MyClass>(firstArg, secondArg);
```

Please keep in mind that NSubstitute can not work with non-virtual methods, and when substituting for classes (rather than interfaces) there are some occasions when real code can be executed.

This is explained a bit further in [Creating a substitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/).

Comment: Yeah, but how can i create a substitute of a real class that does not execute real code but instead calls only the callback passed to it. I tried it using the [when-do callbacks](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks), though it calls the callback, it still also calls the real code. If not, can it be achieved with moq?

Comment: Constructor code and code in non-virtual members will always run. I believe Moq, FakeItEasy and RhinoMocks have similar constraints, although it's worth checking with those projects and/or posting a general .net mocking question to SO. Best way to ensure real code will not run is to use an interface (as they have no real code). If you can't edit original class, one option is to use the adapter pattern to make the original class conform to the interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have finally resolved the problem and gotten the test to pass by mocking the `IUserStore<Account>` and `IUserPhoneNumberStore<Account>` using the Moq extension method and returning the desired `Task<IdentityResult>`. Although it looks a bit messy, but it works.